# Issue with IE7 hiding/removing/showing content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

So I have a bit of script at the bottom of my page *//RETAINER CURRENT* that is supposed to hide and show content based on what menu item the user selects in the maincontent area. Unfortunately in **IE7** all layers are rendered which means the videos in each layer play simultaneous. I tried .detach, .remove, methods and had no luck and when I saved the items to an array and .empty 'd them I still had no success. What noob mistake am I making?

http://jsbin.com/ahuye4/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I was using asp.net so the way I was able to solve this was by using updatepanels and handling the hiding/showing in the code behind with Panels.

I'm not sure what fraemwork/language you are using.

However, I think you might need to call into the flash object and pause/stop the flash videos programmatically.

Comment: I ended up deciding to destroy and build each video when the user clicks on each video link. jQuery pulls the link information and inserts it with the rest of the output into the div holding the video player.